jupyter notebook extension / IDE idea - general/preliminary inquiry
I have an idea for a Jupyter notebook extension that I think might help me (and hopefully other people) in a limited by meaningful way. I want to gauge whether to:

take this on as a personal sidequest (might learn a lot but take way more time than I want to devote to a hypothetical outcome at the moment, as I am start from near zero in notebook extension world)
try to determine whether it already exists in some form
try to find someone for whom it would be hopefully/relatively trivial to make this and/or who might appreciate the idea as something to help people general

Here is the idea:
I don't type well and I also suspect I may have some intermittent dyspraxia that is making it worse. For this and (many) other reasons, I think a lot about accessibility. When I am writing functions in Jupyter notebook/lab, I often suspect it would be helpful to toggle between carriage-returned/'PEP8-ed' and single-line formatts of the same function or code block. It helps with visibility and also experimentation (e.g. commenting a parameter in and out).
Toy example:
import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[4,5,6],title='title')

toggles (as entire cell, whole notebook, or selected text) via nbextension + command pallette shortcut to:
px.scatter(
           x=[1,2,3],
           y=[4,5,6],
           # title='title' # <-- see what I am getting at?
)

That's it, really. For now, anyway.
Does this exist?
If not, is there someone who might see value and would might consider making it?
If not, is there someone willing to give me some breadcrumps on how to get from A to B without getting lost in the weeds here?
asking a preliminary question about how to approach this

partially it exists in programs for code formatting or linters but rather only in one direction - from wrong formatted to correctly formatted. I think it may need to work with AST (abstract syntax tree)
